CVE issue due to GO binary
I have a go binary in my docker image and its causing CVE issues, like this, and it states:

The go command may execute arbitrary code at build time when using
cgo. This may occur when running "go get" on a malicious module, or
when running any other command which builds untrusted code. This is
can by triggered by linker flags, specified via a "#cgo LDFLAGS"
directive. Flags containing embedded spaces are mishandled, allowing
disallowed flags to be smuggled through the LDFLAGS sanitization by
including them in the argument of another flag. This only affects
usage of the gccgo compiler.

I am not able to understand how it impacts the docker images, and how to get rid of it.
Any lead is appreciated.
PS: Binary in question is telegraf

which version of go you are using?

The binary is built upon 1.19.1.

upgrade to latest version of go 1.22

I dont have option to update binary version. Is it possible to somehow remove problematic parts of the binary itself.

Do you have the go executable (i.e. the compiler) or an executable compiled from Go sources? The use of the term "go binary" is ambiguous. Also, it would help if you provided info where you get this report, i.e. provide more context, perhaps even a way to reproduce this.

I have updated the post with link to the binary.

The issue CVE-2023-29405 is not relevant for already build images, only during build time. When you have a pre-build image inside a docker file, it is irrelevant.
Vulnerability Report GO-2023-1842: “This only affects usage of the gccgo compiler.”
How you can get rid of false positives depends on who issues the warning. Usually you can turn stuff like this off.
